# SQL and aggregation by multiple groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a MySQL query that returns a list of recipients who have received at least $1000 in at most three transactions.

Here is an example of a table (The first column is recipients (text column) and the second corresponds to his/ her transaction amount (int)):

```
recipient  amount 
1          200
1          10000
2          100
2          10
3          500
4          400
4          400
4          200
3          200
3          100
```

I understand how to do it:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having count(*) <= 3 and
       sum(amount) >= 1000;
```

But in the task given the next note: "note that, there can be more than three transactions to that recipient, as long as three or fewer transactions amount to at least $1000"

I am totally stuck and cannot find an answer online.

Comment: What version of mySQL?  Are window/analytic functions available.?

Comment: @xQbert This task I tried to solve online on one site. I'm not sure about window/analytic functions.

Comment: You could limit the amounts to be the top 3 for each recipient and then sum if the top 3 don't total at least 1000 then you know that none will; regardless of how many.  Basically replace t above with a derived table only contain the top 3 amounts for each recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming perfomance is not your main concern, this should work and also show recipients that have more than 3 transactions but their top 3 amount to more than 1000 :

```
select distinct t1.recipient
from 
  (select recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t1 
left join
  (select recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t2
on t1.recipient = t2.recipient and t2.amount < t1.amount 

left join
  (select recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t3
     on t1.recipient = t3.recipient and t3.amount < t2.amount

where 
  t1.amount + coalesce(t2.amount, 0) + coalesce(t3.amount, 0) >= 1000;
```

After some more thought on the matter, you would actually need a seperate unique column to make this work 100% of the time. As you can cleary check, the recipient "4" is not shown here. 
We can remedy this fact by using another id column and comparing the amount value with <= instead of < :

```
select distinct t1.recipient
from 
  (select id,recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t1 
left join
  (select id,recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t2
on t1.recipient = t2.recipient and t1.id <> t2.id and t2.amount <= t1.amount 

left join
  (select id,recipient,amount from t order by amount desc) t3
     on t1.recipient = t3.recipient and t1.id<>t3.id and t3.id<>t2.id and t3.amount <= t2.amount

where 
  t1.amount + coalesce(t2.amount, 0) + coalesce(t3.amount, 0) >= 1000;
```

Answer (score -1):

This one of the ways to do it. You first select the recipients that have not more than 3 entries, and then you filter the sum only within  that set of recipients:

```
SELECT recipient 
FROM usr GROUP BY recipient 
HAVING recipient IN 
    (SELECT recipient AS c FROM usr GROUP BY recipient HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3)  AND 
    sum(amount) >= 1000
```

Comment: If i understand the task correctly, then a recipient can have more than 3 transactions and still be in the result set, if he reaches the 1000 with at most 3 of those.

Comment: "returns a list of recipients who have received at least $1000 in at most three transactions" I understand it that we ignore those that have more than 3 entries. And among the rest, we look for total amount higher than 1000. If this is not the expected result then my answer is not relevant. The author of the question should clarify.

Comment: I was referring to the last section of the question "But in the task given the next note: "note that, there can be more than three transactions to that recipient, as long as three or fewer transactions amount to at least $1000""